# Log File Analyzer for Java developers

Tags: windows, logging, log4j

Sorry to raise this question. But I see a need to update the best log analyzer tools list.

I used BairTail. It's simple and fast. But the development stopped in 2007 and never updated thereafter and no search functionality for free users

Then moved to LogExpert, it's good and free with search functionality. But it's damn slow when log size goes by 2-3mb and scrolling is pain

Apache Chainsaw, other than it's from Apache, i would say it's pretty hard for developer who wants to analyze logs bit fast without doing all regex and manual work. It's too much deviation from normal usage and pretty slow

Please suggest one good/best Log Analyze tool [freeware]

1. Simple Search functionality and highlight is must
2. Should run smooth with minimum cpu resources
3. It will  be used upto analyzing 30-50mb files
4. Scrolling and GUI friendly. I use in windows environment and need GUI tools only

Comment: Not even a single tool exist?

Answer (score 6):

I used [otroslogviewer](http://code.google.com/p/otroslogviewer/) to analyze generated logfiles on windows. I used it with 500MB files without any performance or stability. It's free, open scource and the development is still active. It has a pattern auto detect for Java.util.logging or you can pass in your PatternLayout from log4j or describe your custom setup to parse the log messages. You can search (optional with RegEx), mark and filter results and use highlighting (for stacktraces or XML etc.). It's the best choise for me, I found in the web.

Comment: It's bit good now. But still the GUI Scrolling is slow. Not to say JAVA apps are like that. they are terribly slow compared to any C# or C++ apps. One more, I opened my log and says it can't find matching pattern and go to some link to how to add. Do I really need all this to just analyze one log file. If tomorrow I open one of my server box and download log file and to read, I need to to do this process again as I don't know what the developer uses. Even If i know, isn't it too much work rather than understanding log

Answer (score 1):

The latest developer snapshot of Chainsaw is much improved.  You don't need to use regexps, just type a word in the search or filter box to get a case-insensitive partial text match (single quotes around it if it's more than one word)..

Chainsaw now has the ability to annotate the notes (click in the 'marker' field), provides tons of ways to customize the UI, and has an improved config screen (you can build a Chainsaw config by giving it your log4j config file containing a fileappender definition)..It's maybe worth giving it another look.

Developer snapshot available here:
http://people.apache.org/~sdeboy

Comment: I just now tried latest version. Seriously i don't think i am not going to suggest for even my enemy. It's terribly slow and GUI is worst. Open Log, popups a browse window (but i can't paste any address, it doesn't have address bar). Seriously do i need to go folder by folder to get locate my file. Sorry if i am speaking bad, but it's not a good choice at all

Comment: Wow..well..if you're on a Mac, that's the standard file-open dialog.  But..you're using the wrong option - you need to select the 'File, Load Chainsaw configuration' option, and pass in your original log4j.xml with your fileappender definition, or use the 'process a log file' option.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents..
I'm afraid you will not find a **free** piece of software which does what you ask for. Here are some reasons coming to mind.

1. formats of plain text log files are madly fragmented, it's very hard to make it useful - you asked for good quality and simplicity of use, right?. It may sound simple, but it's not. To make it user friendly makes it even more complicated, free software never worries too much about usability.
2. open source (or freebees) don't do GUI stuff in general, aside from several exceptions, so don't expect to find state of the art user interfaces. Open source is great with frameworks, libraries, server stuff, and never with UI and definitely not with usability.
3. Serious log analysis tool based on files is strange to put it gently. To do the analysis one needs structured data. Crunching heaps of data in GUI app is not practical. This is why nobody bothered to create anything like this and give it away.

So, you will find bits of this puzzle separately - you will find some cool log parser for free, or you will find some cool log viewer for free, you will find indexer and fantastic data storage for logs.. But you will never find a **free** complete solution for the reasons above mentioned.

Comment: You have seperated everything and gave good clarification. Indeed I am looking for Log Viewer which can meet my requirements.

Comment: We have a commercial product doing this (for disclosure - I am the developer, look at my signature). But we don't work with files because it's not economically feasible to crunch thousands of odd file formats and stay profitable. And it's not technically possible to do reasonable log analysis on large scale without proper back-end.